# How to evaluate square of a binom in coq?

Tags: coq

I have reached a point in a structural induction proof where I have 2 equivalent algebraic expressions on different sides of the equation. One of them is just expanded form of another. I hoped `reflexivity .` would catch up on that, but apparently I still need some simplification. I'm not sure however what command can help me here.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a job for the `ring` tactic (which requires `Require Import Ring`). In case this is about `nat` (which does not form a ring) you might be able to convert your goal to `Z` using the `zify` tactic (which should be included in `Require Import Lia`). In case your term is linear (does not multiply variables) you can also try `lia` instead of ring.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell why `reflexivity` does not work without looking at your code.  You might need a few rewriting steps before reflexivity can do the job.  Note that sometimes two expressions might look definitionally equal when they are printed even though they actually aren't. For instance, there could be invisible implicit arguments that are not definitionally equal and that are preventing unification. It might help to use `Set Printing All` to double check if you are missing such issues.

Comment: Great answer. I would add that there are [other printing flags](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#printing-constructions-in-full) one can test that are less verbose than `Set Printing All`. In my experience, `Set Printing Coercions` and/or `Set Printing Implicit` are usually enough, but YMMV. Another one that can be useful if the problem is a misunderstanding of notation associativity is [`Set Printing Parentheses`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#coq:flag.Printing-Parentheses).